# jquery looping through input fields and going into parent and siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello all Im stuck with some code hoping to get help. I have my html set up like so:

```
     <div class="menu_options">
           <div class="parent_options">
               <input type="checkbox" class="parent_required" />
           </div>
           <div class="children">
                 <div class="child_options">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="child_required" />   
                 </div>
                 <div class="child_options">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="child_required" />   
                 </div>
                 <div class="child_options">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="child_required" />   
                 </div>
           </div>
      </div>
```

Basically what im trying to do is in jquery if the parent_required class checkbox is checked get all the input fields under the children class and all input fields class by child_required uncheck them.

I cannot use id' on the input fields because i just dont know all the id's for the fields to use.

so far in jquery i have this code

```
      $('.parent_required').click(function() {

            if(!$(this).is(":checked")) {
                var child = $(this).parent('.parent_options').siblings('.children');

            }
        });
```

and im suck here at the div class='children part dont know how to get deeper in.

Comment: What do you have against unordered lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.parent_required').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('.parent_options')
            .siblings('.children')
            .find('.child_required')
            .prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T9uBC/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.parent_required').click(function() {

  if(!$(this).is(":checked")) {
    // this gives you the <div class="children">
    var child = $(this).closest('. menu_options').find('.children');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `change` instead of `click` for parent_required:

```
$('.parent_required').change(function() {

    if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.parent_required').parents('.menu_options').find('.child_required').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the nodenames, type attributes or classes of the inputs if you don't know the ids, there is no reason to use absolute DOM paths.

Also, your [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) invocation will only return the `<div class="parent_options">`, yet you need the `<div class="menu_options">` to select children from there:

```
$('.parent_required').click(function() {
    if (!this.checked)
        $(this)
          .closest('.menu_options')
          .find(':checkbox.child_required')
          .prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
    $('.parent_required').on('change', function() {

            if(!$(this).is(":checked")) {
               $(this).closest('.parent_options')
                      .next('.children').find('.child_required').attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/evoreq/1/edit

Here you go up with the `closest` method from the parent checkbox untill you find 'parent_options', then you take the 'next' element which has a 'children' class, find all the 'child_required' elements inside it, and set the checked attribute to false.